# nested array index python

Tags: list, nested

```
scores = [[0,0]]*10
scores[1][1] += 1
print(scores)
>>[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

I want to increment at a specific position in a nested list in python, but am incrementing the entire list instead.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is because python is first creating the `list`, then is creating the reference ten times. In other words, using this method only one list is created. Try this:

```
scores = []
for i in range(10):
    scores.append([0, 0])
scores[1][1] += 1
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`scores = [[0,0]]*10` makes 10 copy of the same objects. If you examine the `id()` of the list's elements, for example by `id(scores[3])`, you can see their references are the same. If you want to have different objects in your list, you should use something like: `scores = [[0,0] for i in range(10)]`